# Как поменять контактные данные в 1С-Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Как поменять контактные данные в 1С-Битрикс, например, номер телефона?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я менял руками в файле /include/telephone.php в админке не нашел

Answer (score 1):

Данная область является включаемой. Вы можете её изменить в режиме правки.

[image: режим правки]